# Windows 10 displays gibberish text in some apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, language, windows-insider

After a recent windows 10 (windows insider) update I'm getting gibberish text instead of English in some apps

[image: Gibberish text inside IrfanView dialog]

The windows fonts view in control panel is showing gibberish letters for some fonts too (fonts with the codepage number 1255 in their name)

[image: text]

I'm using Hebrew for non-Unicode languages (the problem doesn't exist when non-Unicode language is set to English).
I tried reinstalling Hebrew language, copying default windows 10 fonts.
My brother`s pc with same OS has this problem too.

Comment: After creators update I have the same problem with Hellenic non-unicode software but settings are ok.

Comment: Having the same issue on multiple computers.

Comment: Just FYI, I opened an issue on the Microsoft forums at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-english-system-text-show-as-gibberish/93cd572c-886e-419b-8889-531cff288223 and linked back to this thread.

Comment: @elad Wrong link? I see the 2015 thread

Comment: Yes, sorry, the correct link is: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-creators-update-gibberish-in-some-apps/3afb363d-eaab-49df-a681-b999797fda41

Comment: This issue is now fixed https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020102/windows-10-update-kb4020102 "Addressed issue where some non-Unicode fonts (Courier, MS Sans Serif, etc.) do not render characters correctly on non-Latin, single-byte system locales (Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, etc.). Black bars or other artifacts appear instead."

Comment: @YisroelTech You can add this comment as an answer and I will approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was a Windows issue and is already fixed with a Windows Update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020102/windows-10-update-kb4020102

> Addressed issue where some non-Unicode fonts (Courier, MS Sans Serif,
>   etc.) do not render characters correctly on non-Latin, single-byte
>   system locales (Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, etc.). Black bars or other
>   artifacts appear instead.

Answer (score 6):

Method 1 in this link fixed my problem after creators update:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-english-system-text-show-as-gibberish/93cd572c-886e-419b-8889-531cff288223

> Change Language settings through Control Panel.
>
> - Type `Control Panel` into the search bar on desktop and select the same from the list.
> - Click on *Clock, Language, and Region*.
> - Click *Region*, then go to *Administrative* tab.
> - Make sure that English (United States) is displayed under *Current language for non-Unicode programs* or as per your region. If not
>     change it to the same. If it ask to reboot your PC, do the same.
>
> Now check if it return back to normal language. If in case you need to
>   make changes to the font and restore it to default, then follow with
>   the below steps.
>
> - Type `Control Panel` into the search bar on desktop and select the same from the list. *Click Appearance and Personalization*, and then
>     click *Fonts*.
> - In the left pane, click *Font settings*.
> - Click *Restore default font settings*. Then restart your PC and check if it take changes.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Also that's hardly a solution, as I do actually NEED the Non-Unicode Languages to work with Hebrew in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is obsolete for newer versions of Windows 10. @ramiwi, please consider accepting this one instead.

Here's another **version-free** way to fix this based on [Microsoft's Hebrew answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/forum/all/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9/acb29362-2690-4214-8b01-0cfb2dbf500a).

Microsoft doesn't admit it, but obviously the answer is that even if you installed Hebrew for non-Unicode programs, it might have been installed wrong, so the solution is to choose another language, and only then bring back Hebrew, thus triggering a re-installation of it.

1. Enter `Control Panel=>Region=>Administrative`
2. Do you have Hebrew there?

   1. If not, click `Change system locale...` and change to Hebrew.
   2. If yes, click `Change system locale...` and change to anything else, most helpful is to **English (United States)**.
3. Click `OK`
4. Agree to Restart

After the restart, **only** if you **originally** had Hebrew there, then:

1. Go back to `Control Panel=>Region=>Administrative`
2. Click `Change system locale...` and change to Hebrew.
3. Click `OK`
4. Agree to Restart

[image: Region=>Administrative screen]

[image: Region=>Administrative screen=>Select language]